# QTip with JQGrid using Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid, qtip

I have a jqgrid that has a hyperlink for the ID field within the grid.
What I like to do is when somebody hovers over the id hyperlink that is in Jqgrid, I like to show 
a qTip with the ID selected- http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/.
I actually like to go one step further - when somebody hovers over the ID hyperlink, I like to use JSON and return a string and then display that strin in the QTip

I tried the following:

```
     $(this).qtip({
              content: {
              text: $(this).attr('title'),
         }
     });
```

Comment: It's unclear how exactly you create the link inside of jqGrid. Do you use `formatter: "showlink"` or some other way? Do you see already the tooltip with the text which you need and you want just to change it's look and so you want use `qtip`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax for details on using Ajax/JSON data with qTip.

Comment: Thanks. But how do you use it with JQGrid is what I need -

Comment: I don't have a demo. It is on my local system

Comment: I can't give you a better answer right now, but I retagged your question.